# How to get the supervisors that have approved all the submitted assessment

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project in Laravel-5.8

```
class Employee extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'employees';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id';

   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'fist_name',
              'last_name',
      'supervisor_id',
     ];

   public function assessment()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EmployeeAssessment', 'id', 'employee_id'); 
   }

   public function supervisor()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Employee', 'id', 'supervisor_id');
   }     
}


class Assessment extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'employee_assessments';

   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'employee_id',
              'is_submitted',
              'is_approved',
     ];

   public function employee()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Employee','employee_id');
   }
}
```

Each Employee have a Supervisor, and Supervisor would have more than one Employee reporting to him.
The Employees are to submit their assessment which is to be approved by the supervisor. If the employee submits his assessment, then the is_submitted is 1, else 0.
The supervisor can only approve submitted (is_submitted = 1) assessment. When he approves is_approved is 1.

```
$employees_that_submitted_assessment = Assessment::where('is_submitted', 1)->get();   //Note:If the submitted assessment approved, is_approved = 1 else 0 

$supervisor_completed_approvals = Employee::get();
```

How do I complete the query above to select the supervisors that have approved all the submitted assessments?

NOTE: All is:approved must be 1 for every where the is_submitted is 1 for the employees attached to the supervisor.

Comment: in Employee  Model check supervisor() function ..  is that  okay @mikefolu ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor - Yes, check supervisor() function. Each Employee have a supervisor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using query builder. I believe it would look something like this:

```
Employee::query()
    ->whereNull('supervisor_id')
    ->whereNotIn('supervisor_id', function($query){
        $query->select('employee_id')
            ->from('employee_assignments')
            ->join('employee_assignments', 'employee.id', '=', 'employee_assignments.employee_id')
            ->where('employee_assignments.is_submitted', '=', 1)
            ->where('employee_assignments.is_approved', '=', 0);
    })->get();
```

That makes use of a subquery. The subquery gets the employees with submitted but not approved assignments. The parent query then gets employees who are supervisors (assuming a null supervisor_id represents that) and who aren't supvervisors of employees in the list the subquery returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing your is_approved column to approved_by if you need to track that information, since an employee may change supervisors in the future I would imagine.

In that case you can add the following relationships

Employee.php

```
    public function supervised()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'superviser_id');
    }

    public function approvals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Assessment::class, 'approved_by');
    }

    public function supervisedAssessments()
    {
        return Assessment::whereHas('employee.supervisor' function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', $this->id);
        })->get();
    }

    public function pendingApprovals()
    {
        return Assessment::whereNull('approved_by')
                   ->where('is_submitted', 1)
                   ->whereHas('employee.supervisor' function ($query) {
                       $query->where('id', $this->id);
                   })->get();
    }

    public function approve(Assessment $assessment)
    {
        $assessment->approved_by = $this->id;
        $assessment->save();
    }
```

Assessment.php

```
    public function approvedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'approved_by')
    }
```

Now you can approve assessments with whatever logic you like, as below:

```
foreach ($supervisor->pendingAssessments() as $assessment) {
    $supervisor->approve($assessment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$employees_that_submitted_assessment = Assessment::with(['employee' => function($e)
{
   $e->with('supervisor');
}])
->where('is_submitted', 1)->get();
```

when you will dd($employees_that_submitted_assessment ); you will find supervisor

Answer (score 0):

You have to proper design your Eloquent Model Relationship. As I can see, you did not provide the relationship between EmployeeAssessment and Supervisor objects. According to your assessment scenario, a supervisor can at least have one employee assessment and many occurrences of assessments must be handled by a supervisor. So we have one-to-many relationship between Supervisor and EmployeeAssessment.

You need to consider something like this:

1. Eloquent Model Relationship

   ```
   class Supervisor extends Model{
       public function employeeAssessment(){
           return $this->hasMany('App\EmployeeAssessment');
       }            
    }

   class EmployeeAssessment extends Model{
       public function supervisor(){
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Supervisor');
       }            
    }
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
       $supervisors = Supervisor::with('employeeassements', 'employee')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(25)->get(); //if you want to limit 25 assessments per query
   ```
3. View

   ```
   @if(!empty($supervisors))
       //traverse the assessment by supervisor with nested loops
       @foreach($supervisors as $supervisor){

           @foreach($supervisor->employeeassements as $assessment){
             //some extra code here using $assessment object

            //count the suppervisors here
            ({{ count(($supervisor->employeeassements) }})
           }
       }
   @endif
   ```